# Enabling webhooks in Pybossa without enabling SSE

Tags: asynchronous, webhooks, pybossa

I have been working with the Webhooks in Pybossa. According to their [documentation](http://docs.pybossa.com/en/latest/customizing.html) (Enabling Server Sent Events), for enabling webhooks, we need to execute Pybossa in asynchronous mode with SSE enabled. But, running Pybossa in asynchronous mode carries with it many issues. Is there any way to enable Webhooks with SSE disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to enable SSE for webhooks. That's only to get a better experience when debugging webhooks from the PYBOSSA server. Disable them, and run normally. SSE is only used to not force to reload the webhooks admin page so you can deploy payloads to your webhooks server without reloading the entire page. Nothing else.